# Can two DNS server have same name?

Tags: dns, hostname

I have a question regarding DNS which I was asked in an interview and I was bit confused.

The question is, if I have two DNS server can those two DNS server have a same name?

I asked this question to some of them but I got different answers, one said **Yes** the two DNS server can have the same name.
Another guy said **No** for it, and said it might bring conflict. And another guy told me 'I am not sure'... yes it can have same DNS server name but not in the same domain.

And this is confusing me a lot, is it ****YES** or **NO**** please give an simple explanation. And the last guy said yes but no for the same domain, I didn't completely  understand this.

Comment: Can you give examples of what you mean?  Although honestly, after reading this I fear that having you provide examples would still be confusing.  If you mean... I have two separate computers that each act as DNS servers.  Can I name them each dns1.niteshdns.com?  Or do I have to name one dns1.niteshdns.com and the other dns2.niteshdns.com.... then could you explain that better?  Otherwise, what exactly do you mean when you say "the same name"?

Comment: Have two different DNS servers with the same name would create a conflict.

Comment: Same name, different IPs and going into a load balancer to serve each out round robin?

Comment: I have two computers that acts as a DNS servers. Now can i have them both with the same name dns1.niteshdns.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would generally keep both dns servers with different names if you're talking about the actual computer names, I can't think of any situation where naming two dns servers the same would be helpful at all and would most likely just cause confusion and even name resolutions issues, you should use one as a primary and another as a secondary for most setups.

Comment: DNS Servers in a cluster?

Comment: I assume you're trying to balance the load of name resolution between two dns servers? Are these Virtual machines in a cluster?

Answer (score -1):

The main point is that you machine isnt just the machine name `TACODNS` its altually `com.bobstacoemporium.TACODNS` or `net.billsburritoshack.TACODNS`

Thats what's called a [FQDN](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFully_qualified_domain_name&ei=tElOUtmDPJGo4AOXk4HgDg&usg=AFQjCNH57MCk4a9ZpU2SDKQ1Sbcxp-Lz8Q&sig2=W9bUm7gEA2fqhyYjKo5_xg&bvm=bv.53537100,d.dmg) or a Full Qualified Domain Name. The important thing is that machines in a DIFFERENT DOMAIN with the same machine name (`TACODNS`) would not have the same FQDN.

Any computers that need to talk to their DNS server are going to ask for TACODNS, but they will tag their main name on there to find it. So Bob's computers find Bob's , and Bill's computer's find Bill's. A beautiful thing, name resolution....

---

### TL;DR

-If they are in the SAME Domain, then NO; they need to have different names or they will keep trying to fight over it and you're poor little member computers are goingto have a hell of a time. You'll need a `TACODNS` and a `BurritoDNS`.

If they are in DIFFERENT domains, you're GOOD TO GO. Feel free to name both of them `TACODNS` because  is `com.bobstacoemporium.TACODNS` or `net.billsburritoshack.TACODNS`

---